# Getting a variable globaly

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get prijs from the selectboxid .change() function to number1 .change() function. So can anybody help me fix this mess???

```
$.each(product, function(key, value) {
    $('#selectboxid')
        .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", key)
            .text(value.omschrijving));
});


$('#selectboxid').change(function(prijs) {
    //Use $option (with the "$") to see that the variable is a jQuery object
    var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    //Added with the EDIT
    var value = $option.val(); //to get content of "value" attrib
    var text = $option.text(); //to get <option>Text</option> content
    var prijs = product[value].prijs;
    $(".prijs").html(product[value].prijs);
    $(".tarief").html(product[value].tarief + "%");

});


$('#number1').change(function(prijs) {

    console.log(prijs);
    var number1 = $("input#number1").val();
    alert(number1);


});
```

Comment: you want ` product[value].prijs` to be into the #number1 input?

Comment: as a selected value?

Comment: Var number1 is a number input field. on change of the number input i want to change the price of the product by the selected number